# Separating the Tridion Deployer and Upload Service for Outscaling

Tags: tridion

I have a diagram (SDL) showing a scenario where the deployer is split into the HTTP Upload services running on n servers and the Deployer services running on n servers, sharing storage for the uploaded packages - I'm curious how this would be configured as it doesn't make sense at first glance, has anyone done it this way?

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine your deployers are looking at a network mapped shared directory for their 'incoming' directory?

I'd also imagine your services are service based deployers, where your http uploads are of the web-based flavour.

Perhaps you could share your diagram?

Comment: That's the premise - it's more how the configuration would work and what the benefits are of this configuration?

Comment: In the installation package, under \Content Delivery\roles you can find the separate modules. The benefits - separation of concerns and scalability.